# Jibx vs JXPath in terms of performance

Tags: java, performance, jibx, jxpath

Dealing with a project in which huge volumes of XML files are processed and loaded into RDBMS. 
In the tranformation layer, XML file needs to be converted to java pojo , enriched validated and then inserted into DB.

The file size is appx. 10 kb

Question is, in transformation layer which framework to use
1) JIBX(with woodstox)
2) jxpath
Jxpath will come handy to develop a configurable transformation layer as it is expression based and we can dynamically evaluate the path with conditions.
However on the other hand, I am concerned about the performance.

I havent tried my hands yet on both the approaches. Appreciate your advise.

Comment: im useing jibx for ex/importing data from our system. it's ligthning fast - around 3 secs for a ~10Mb file with ~50k objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried VTD, and i am very happy with the performance.